# What do the boolean attributes "firstInFirstChain" and "firstInSecondChain" of a RelationshipRecord mean?

Tags: neo4j

I found the [source code file](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/store/record/RelationshipRecord.java) of "RelationshipRecord" of Neo4j.
I think, I understand the first 7 attributes.

But there are 2 more boolean attributes "firstInFirstChain" and "firstInSecondChain".
[image]
What are they good for?